# picture visible = true if cell contains data

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out simple code to make picture objects visible if particular cells contain data. Cells in range R12:R61 contains objects (pictures, ie. Round Rectangles) that are not visible (.visible = false).
If some cells in range P12:P61 contains data then corresponding hidden image in range R12:R61 of that row need to be visible. I've tried something like this:

```
Dim xPicRg As Range
Dim xPic As Picture
Dim xRg As Range

Set xRg = Range("R12:R61")
For Each xPic In ActiveSheet.Pictures
Set xPicRg = Range(xPic.TopLeftCell.Address & ":" & xPic.BottomRightCell.Address)
If Not Intersect(xRg, xPicRg) Is Nothing Then xPic.Visible = True
Next
```

I'm stuck with this one.

Comment: With intersect you are now checking if the image intersects the whole range you're checking (R12:R61). If images are bound to cells, you could check if the value left of the top left corner of the pic is empty like this: `xPic.TopleftCell.Offset(0,-1).Value2 = ""`

Comment: What does "corresponding hidden image" mean? Is there in the range a single shape? If yes, please tell us what "contains objects (pictures, ie. Round Rectangles)" should mean. If not, please define the correspondence in discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine our input looking like this:

[image]

Then, working with Range("A1:B10"), the only picture that should be present is the one in rows 1 and 2, as for the other 3 there are numbers in column "A":

```
Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim checkRange As Range
    Dim myPic As Picture
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Set checkRange = .Range("A1:B10")
        Dim myRow As Range
        For Each myRow In checkRange.Rows
            If WorksheetFunction.Count(myRow.Cells) > 0 Then
                For Each myPic In .Pictures
                    Debug.Print myPic.TopLeftCell.Address
                    Debug.Print myPic.BottomRightCell.Address
                    
                    Dim picRange As Range
                    Set picRange = .Range(.Cells(myPic.TopLeftCell.Row, myPic.TopLeftCell.Column), _
                        .Cells(myPic.BottomRightCell.Row, myPic.BottomRightCell.Column))
                    Debug.Print picRange.Address
                    
                    If Not Intersect(picRange, myRow) Is Nothing Then
                        myPic.Visible = False
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```